# Pass uint8_t* as parameter to raw function pointer

Tags: c++, windows, function-pointers, uint8array, getprocaddress

I have the problem where I want to pass a `uint8_t[]` array as a parameter to a function pointer defined as `typedef void (*dangerousC)(void*); Also, I'm using Windows API headers.

Assume the variable `raw` is a function pointer returned by `GetProcAddress()`. Also assume that the parameters to `foo()` are not known by the compiler.

Here is the full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef void (*dangerousC)(char*);

void foo(int a) {
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto raw = (FARPROC) foo;

    auto* b = new uint8_t[4];
    b[0] = 74;
    b[1] = 35;
    b[2] = 0;
    b[3] = 0;

    std::cout << *(int*)b << std::endl;
    auto func = (dangerousC)raw;
    func(reinterpret_cast<char *>(*b));
    delete[] b;
}
```

When I call the function pointer with the parameters `reinterpret_cast<char *>(*b)`, I only get one character, which is reasonable when I dereference a pointer.

But I also tried with a pointer and it does not print the result that I want, which is 9034.

How could I make the function print 9034 and fully interpret the byte array as a 32-bit int?

Comment: *I also tried with a pointer* It's unclear what have you tried. Please show a code.

Comment: Does `*(int*)b` do what you expect? Don't you see that `reinterpret_cast<char *>(*b)` is completely different?

Comment: I tried reinterpret_cast<char *>(*b) and reinterpret_cast<char *>(b). But I don't really know how to force the compiler to read the extra bytes I give it.

Comment: Im trying to give the function pointer data at runtime, so the compiler wouldn't know if the data is an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo()` expects an `int`, but you are passing it a `char*` instead. As such, you need to pass in a `char*` whose *value* is the integer you want, not an actual pointer to an integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef void (*dangerousC)(char*);

void foo(int a) {
   std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto raw = (FARPROC) foo;

    uint8_t b[4];
    b[0] = 74;
    b[1] = 35;
    b[2] = 0;
    b[3] = 0;

    int32_t i = *reinterpret_cast<int32_t*>(b);
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    auto func = reinterpret_cast<dangerousC>(raw);
    func(reinterpret_cast<char*>(i));
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Af-sfMomC)

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's done like below, as I understood it from your comment properly, you deal with byte streams

```
int n;
std::memcpy(&n, b, sizeof(n));
func(b);
```

Comment: I figured it out and made it work with uint8_t* pointers instead.

    auto* ptr = new uint8_t[4];
    memcpy(&ptr, b, 4);
    func(ptr);

this for some weird reason worked for me, but thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @block103 You are creating a memory leak, as you are overwriting a pointer to `new`d memory. You shouldn't be using `new` at all.